# Chart.register is not a function error in chart.js

Tags: reactjs, build, chart.js, react-chartjs

Whenever I am running my application locally it is running fine, but when building it as a component I get an error that says, Chart.register is not a function. Can someone please help.

My Code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Chart, CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement } from 'chart.js'
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2'

Chart.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement)
function SpectrumAllocation() {
  const options = {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    elements: {
      bar: {
        borderWidth: 2
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'right'
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Horizontal Bar Chart'
      }
    }
  }

  const labels = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July'
  ]

  const data = {
    labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        data: [12, 23, 34, 45, 56],
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)'
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        data: [12, 23, 34, 45, 56],
        borderColor: 'rgb(53, 162, 235)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(53, 162, 235, 0.5)'
      }
    ]
  }

  return <Bar options={options} data={data} />
}

export default SpectrumAllocation
```

I tried to import Chart from "chart.js/auto" and also I tried to import {Chart} from "chart.js", but none of them worked. Downgrading the chart.js version is also something I tried but got nothing out of it.

Comment: Have you tried the standard way, recommended by `react-chartjs-2` in [Quickstart](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/#quickstart) `import {Chart as ChartJS, ...} ...` - maybe the `react-chartjs-2` import on the next line messes with the global variable (class) `Chart`

Comment: Did that as well. Didn't work.

Comment: What exactly is the value of `Chart`( or `ChartJS`)? What do you get by a `console.log(Chart)` before the call to `Chart.register`? It must be defined, by the error message you get - otherwise it would've been `Chart is not defined`

Comment: When I consoled it, I get to see a class and yes it contains a static register method.

Comment: Then maybe the error is not generated by your `Chart.register` line, don't you get a `console.log` result *after* `Chart.register`?

Comment: The problem comes after the build. Locally everything is fine. When the component is built, chart is undefined.

Comment: Interesting, if `Chart` is `undefined`, and you try `Chart.register(...)`, you'd normally get the error `Chart is not defined`,  not `Chart.register is not a function`